# My Account custom link redirection issue when customer not logged in in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, myaccount

I have added custom link in my account section

view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    -->
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-prescription" after="-">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">prescription</argument>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Prescriptions</argument>
                        <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">5</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

CONTROLLER

```
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface as HttpGetActionInterface;

    class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements HttpGetActionInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var PageFactory
         */
        protected $resultPageFactory;

        /**
         * @param Context $context
         * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            Context $context,
            PageFactory $resultPageFactory
        ) {
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
            $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Prescriptions'));

            $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('customer.account.link.back');
            if ($block) {
                $block->setRefererUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
            }
            return $resultPage;
        }
    }
```

it's working fine for logged in  customer, but when session timtout means customer is not logged in is not redirecting to customer login page.
It's still redirecting on prescription page.
Can anyone help please

Comment: what is your controller code can you add that code in question

Comment: @JigsParmar have added please check

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add the code in di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\History">
        <plugin name="authentication" type="Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\Plugin\Authentication"/>
    </type>
```

you need to put the controller path instead of `Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\History`

Comment: I know this way but why we have to additionally check using customer session.? i have checked in sales/order/history there is no code regarding customer session

Comment: in the file Magento_Sales/etc/di.xml  plugin authentication code is there you can search word Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\History and check

Comment: if you want to execyte same like sales/order/history you need to add code in di.xml like same they put

Comment: Perfect !!!!!!!!!!! Thank you so much

Comment: Please accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: Just update your answer with sales order comment rest i will do

Comment: update my answer

Comment: @JigsParmar ,as per as, the community, you can NOT ask the user give upvote and accept. It is totally user call.

Answer (score 2):

In your controller change `extends` class to `Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount`

Your controller should be -

```
class YourClass extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount
{
//Your Actions code
}
```

For Sales order history controller it is redirected by a plugin, you can find below code in `di.xml` of `Magento_Sales` module

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\History">
        <plugin name="authentication" type="Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\Plugin\Authentication"/>
    </type>
```

Comment: But in Sales/order/History it's not extended why we have to extend it? @Piyush

Comment: it depends on module, for all account action it extends this controller, for sales order there may be another way, may be any plugin or observer

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you put checking in your controller Customer customer session. 
You can try below code in your controller.

I assume your module name is "**Company_MyModle**" and controler class name is Index.php

**Controller : Index.php**

```
<?php 
namespace Company\MyModle\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,    
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);        
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        if (!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account/login');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }       
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this way but why we have to additionally check using customer session.?
i have checked in sales/order/history there is no code regarding customer session